# Android - Prevent TextView from shifting upwards when appended to

Tags: android, xml

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textInput"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="15"
    android:maxEms="15"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:id="@+id/mText"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The `TextView` appears below the `EditText` which is fine and the `TextView` is blank by default. In my code I am appending to the `TextView` over time, but after one line has filled up, the previous line shifts upwards closer to the `EditText` until they are overlapping.

Is there a way for the `TextView` to grow only downwards when text is appended to it, rather than shifting upwards?

To be more clear:

```
EditText                            


first line of BlankTextView
```

Goes to:

```
EditText

first line of TextView <- first line shifted up one place
second line of TextView
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, to be able to define the relative position of your `EditText` and `TextView` to each other, you should add them to the same `RelativeLayout`.

After that, you could use the `android:layout_below` attribute, to position your `TextView` below your `EditText`, to prevent them from overlapping.

Try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textInput"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:ems="15"
            android:maxEms="15"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textInput"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:id="@+id/mText"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```